# How to display a number with 7 digits?

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk

I would like to display a score with 7 digits. I tried to use `string.format()` in vain.

I have a score module and want to display like this : `0000000`

My module add 10 points each time, so it has to be : `0000010` - `0000020` etc...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Integers or floating point numbers? Give an example to explain yourself and what you tried.

Comment: In Excel, Word, c#? Give an example of how you're wanting it to look, I assume you just mean padded with 0s at the front?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(string.format("%07d", 10))
```

Output: `0000010`

`07` in the format specifier means use at least 7 digits, and fills them with leading 0s.